# Multiple Contact Registration for events

Tags: civievent

I'm sure I'm off in my configuration but not sure what.  I've set up an event where a registrant can register multiple participants under the same address. For this event, a parent would sign up and then each of  their children coming to the event would have to be registered

In the set-up, I have the following profiles for On-line Registration:

"Include Profile Top of Page"   Parents Profile
"Profile for Additional Participants"  Youth Profile

I do have the option for "Same e-mail address" selected

Here is the problem...when a user sign's up and uses the same e-mail address, only the first contact is used so I'm seeing that first user registering each time.

Here is the actual scenario.  Parent 1 and Parent 2 have to separate e-mails. Parent 1 registers three children under his e-mail.

Parent 1: parent1@email
Parent 2: parent2@email
Child 1: parent1@email
Child 2: parent1@email
Child 3: parent1@email

When registered in this manner, Parent 1, Parent 2, and Child 1 get confirmation e-mails. Child 2 and 3 get a confirmation e-mail addressed to Child 1.

When I view the participants for the event, I see:

Parent1
Parent2
Child1
Child1
Child1

How can I correct this issue as it's important to have the name of each participant that is joining us.

Comment: I should also add something I just realized.  The contact name for Parent1 was changed to Child1 in Parent 1's contact profile. No idea what that is all about. The parent's name is changed to the child's name.

Comment: Have you got it set to allow multiple registrations for the same email address? Also check your de-dupe rule on the event - might be worth changing it.

Comment: Parvez, I do have the setting set to allow the same e-mail address. The above listed example, all of the children are using the same e-mail as Parent1 and I think is where the issue comes in. I am not too familiar with using the de-duping and am not sure how I would set this to correct the issue.

Comment: You would need to use a de-dupe rule that included First Name and Last Name. I'd give more weight to first name, since last name is more than likely to be the same as the registering parent. Alternately, you could try de-duping based on birthdate and name (in the event of multiples like twins and triplets).

Answer (score 2):

This situation is why there's the ability to pick a specific dedupe rule for your event's online registration.  The information you get in certain cases is quite different than online donations or other events.

First, unless you are using a dedupe rule where email alone is *not* enough points to match, you should **uncheck the Same email address? box**.  The default unsupervised rule says individuals with matching email addresses are the same person, so that's probably causing your problem.

Second, you should consider whether you expect any children to have real, independent email addresses (and whether you'd want those addresses anyway).  If not, make **a profile lacking the email address field** and use it for additional attendees.

Finally, you'll want a strategy for dealing with duplicates.  If you are just collecting first and last names for additional registrants, you don't have much to go by in matching them to contacts.  (There was another Andrew Hunt at my high school.)  Instead of trying to match blindly at the point of registration, it is probably more efficient to let the form create duplicates and then manage the duplicates later.  Here's how:

1. Have your profile for additional attendees add contacts to a group for you to review later
2. You can create a *General* dedupe rule that matches on first and last name.  It won't be good to use on a front-facing form, but you can use it to find duplicates later.
3. From the Find and Merge Duplicate Contacts screen, use that rule from step 2 to find duplicates, selecting the group from step 1.  You'll get a few false positives, but you can mark them as "not a duplicate".  Those pairs won't be suggested ever again.
4. Repeat step 3 every few weeks while your events are getting frequent registrations, and do it at least every couple of months through the rest of the year.